# OleDbException summing two fields within an SQL query C#

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

I am using a OleDbConnection in c#

my query is :

```
"SELECT [City],[Column1]+[Column2]
 FROM  [Issuer$] WHERE ([Column1] > 1)  
 GROUP BY [City]"
```

I always receive the error

```
ERROR : You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified 
expression 'Column1+Column2' as part of an aggregate function.
```

My question is : what am I doing wrong?

I tried to look for people adding field like that but didn't find anyone with the same problem.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a GROUP BY the columns in the select needs to be aggregates of the records that make up the group. So you need to use...

```
SELECT City,
       SUM(Column1 + Column2)
FROM Issuer
WHERE (Column1 > 1)
GROUP BY City
```

...where it will add up all the Column1 + Column2 values for each row in the return group entry.

Comment: I'm assuming  SUM(Column1 **-** Column2) will work too

Comment: Your question has code that adds together the columns values.  Hence it does the same in my answer. Obviously you can alter this to subtract or whatever else makes sense for your application.